# how to use new volume I created and install 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

So I have the installation USB stick. I also created a new volume by shrinking my HD and labeling the unallocated space to make a visible second drive.

How do I install from the stick to the new volume?

Comment: I do recognize that freeze. That usually happens to me trying to run opensource nouveau drivers on a nvidia based system. Can you boot up ubuntu at all? Usually this happens when you try to run firefox or something. Assuming you have nvidia graphics, you should install nvidia drivers. If you have ubuntu installed already, boot ubuntu and press CTRL + ALT + F2 and sign into a text session with your username and password. Then, execute the following commands: first `sudo service lightdm stop` then `sudo apt-get update` next `sudo apt-get install dkms nvidia-current` and finally sudo reboot.

Comment: Again, that assumes you have nvidia graphics. If not, you should open another question and please include specifics on your hardware setup and I'm sure someone will have the answer you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic Windows 7 or older computer.

Boot up your computer from the USB and select install. (Also, be sure you are connected to the internet!).

When you get to the part of the installation where it asks if you want to install Ubuntu **alongside** your current operating system, scroll down and select the option **someting else**.

Here you will be provided with a list of partitions to choose from.

Right click on the desired partition, select resize, and shrink the partition by 2GB and then select OK or whatever.

Then, right-click on your desired partition again, select **ext4** format, and set the mount point to **/**. Select to apply the changes and proceed with the rest of the installation.

By the way, the extra 2GB was needed to create a swap partition. This should automatically be created but if not, just right click on the 2GB unused space and select format **swap**, **linux swap**, or whatever it is and *then* proceed with the installation.

Comment: Ok after I finally installed 14.04 using the USB thumbdrive, I wind up with a screen like this:
http://prntscr.com/69x7pj
Does anyone recognize this freeze? The screen is frozen and I have to unplug the computer for restart.

Comment: I'm also showing a shot of the partition table to show there is no system for the two drives the USB install created.
http://prntscr.com/69x9g7

Comment: Here's shot of the partition table, all healthy but no drive letters?
http://prntscr.com/69xa84

Comment: And before you kick me out of here, a shot of the drive list showing no media:
http://prntscr.com/69xaqu

Comment: It could be that they are windows partitions and not visible to Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu partitions are not typically visible to Windows so they will not show a drive letter. Windows partitions should be visible to Ubuntu but again, drive letters are typically a windows thing so windows partitions should show up as "NTFS" partitions.